# Creating a MIPS Assembler

Tags: java, c, mips, assembly

Are there any reference guides or tutorials for writing a MIPS assembler?

Comment: Do you mean you want to write a program which is a MIPS simulator or that you want to write a program which compiles higher-level code into MIPS assembly language?

Comment: He clearly says "for writing MIPS asm"

Comment: @David: Unless OP is grossly misusing the term "assembler", he's trying to write a program that turns MIPS assembly language into MIPS machine code.

Comment: Why Java tag? o_O MIPS assembler in Java? well... feasible! But why?!

Comment: If I read the other questions of the OP, I can't believe he really want to write an assembler

Comment: maybe the tag is because of MARS, which is a mips simulator written in java; it could be also a good starting point for an assembler (if it is not already implemented)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to actually write an assembler you need to know the format of the executable of the platform you are writing for (ex. [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format)), then you need to use the [MIPS instruction set](http://www.mips.com/products/product-materials/processor/mips-architecture/) as a reference to determine the correct machine code for your .TEXT section. Good luck!